# Change cleverefs conjunction for one reference

Tags: best-practices, cleveref

What is the best practice to use a different conjunction for a single reference with `cleveref`?

**Background:** I would like to produce something like "Theorem~1, Lemma~2 and [external reference]".

If I use

```
\cref{th:1,lem:2} and \cite{ext}
```

I get "Theorem~1 and Lemma~2 and [...]", since `cleveref` sees only the pair of references and not the following `\cite`.

**My current workaround:**

```
{\renewcommand\crefpairgroupconjunction{, }\cref{th:1,lem:2}} and \cite{ext}
```

(Note that I used `\crefpairgroupconjunction` instead of `\crefpairconjunction` since both references have a different type)

Is there a better workaround?

Answer (score 3):

`Cleveref` is clever, not omniscient. It knows nothing about the citation following the cross-reference. One way or another, you're going to have to tell `cleveref` that you want to make an exception to the normal typesetting for this specific cross-reference.

You gain nothing by trying to automate a one-off exception. Just typeset it as you want it to appear "manually":

```
\cref{th:1}, \cref{lem:2} and \cite{ext}
```

No point trying to be too clever here :-)

Comment: Your approach does not work if lem:2 will be promoted to a theorem later on.

Comment: Good point! I would down-vote my own answer...but SE won't let me. The solution in your question is better in this respect. The general point about not trying to automate absolutely everything in LaTeX, particularly in cases where doing it manually is less effort, is always worth bearing in mind though.