# Inconsistent numbering of items between enumitem and enumerate environments

Tags: numbering, enumerate, enumitem

I have used the template presented in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336590/21685) to create the following document.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\crefname{proposition}{Prop.}{props.}
\newlist{enumprp}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[enumprp]{label=\upshape(\alph*),ref=\upshape\theproposition(\alph*)}
\crefalias{enumprpi}{proposition}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{subcreftmpcnt}
\newcommand\alphsubformat[1]{(\alph{#1})}
\newcommand\subcref[2][\alphsubformat]{
\ifcsname r@#2@cref\endcsname
  \cref@getcounter {#2}{\mylabel}
  \setcounter{subcreftmpcnt}{\mylabel}
  \alphsubformat{subcreftmpcnt}
 \else ?? \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{proposition}
\begin{enumprp}
\item One
\item Two
\end{enumprp}
\end{proposition}
\begin{proof}
\begin{enumerate}
\item One
\item Two
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image: Inconsistent numbering]

Observe that the numbering of the items in the proposition statement is `(a)`, `(b)`, whereas the numbering of the items in the proof is `(1)`, `(2)`.

How can I make the numbering in the statement `(1)`, `(2)`? (Actually, I'd rather the numbering be `1.`, `2.`)

Comment: Why using different environments? Use the same in both cases.

Comment: @egreg: Sometimes I need deeply nested numbering, and I don't know how to accomplish this with the `enumitem` environment, so I use the `enumerate` environment, however other times the `enumitem` environment is indispensable to me, since I need to label the items. In either case, I always use the `enumerate` environment in the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\setlist[enumprp]{label=\upshape(\arabic*),ref=\upshape\theproposition(\arabic*)}
```

i.e. `\arabic`, not `\alph`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to make the numbering `1.`, `2.` instead of `(1)`, `(2)`?

Comment: @EvanAad: use `label=\arabic*., ref=\upshape\theproposition~\arabic*`.